# How to get result filtered using property of table reference by foreign key in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to fetch data form SQL Server.

To get data I wrote `var result = Repository.QueryOver<table_reference>().Where(c => c.Amount >100).List()`

Now I want to get result filtered by foreign key reference something like

```
Repository.QueryOver<TaxInvoicePassing>().Where(c => c.Branch.Employee.Salary > 10000).List()
```

How can I achieve this?

One way is iterate for each table's record and then addrange of  results

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `QueryOver`, you can try this:

```
// declare the alias
Branch branch = null;
Employee employee = null;

Session.QueryOver<TaxInvoicePassing>() // get a queryOver of TaxInvoicePassing
       .JoinAlias(t => t.Branch, () => branch) // add a join with Branch
       .JoinAlias(() => branch.Employee, () => employee) // add a join with Employee
       .Where(c => employee.Salary > 10000) // add where filter on employee's salary
       .List();
```

Using `Linq`, it could be done like the expression you asked:

```
Session.Query<TaxInvoicePassing>()
       .Where(c => c.Branch.Employee.Salary > 10000) // this expression will be converted on a join
       .List();
```

I would move these queries inside the repository object instead exposing it.

Comment: How to handle null reference exception in case of Linq. Means as per your example if Branch having no employee then